# A question on warped product Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, normed-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I am studying a text of Riemannian geometry where the author says: Let the product manifold $M=I\times \tilde{M}$ where $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde{M}$ is an $(n-1)-$ dimensional manifold equipped with a Riemannian metric $\tilde{g}$. A warped product Riemannian metric on $M$ can be written as
$$g= dr\otimes dr + w(r) \tilde{g}$$
where $r$ is the standard coordinate on $I$ and $w(r)$ is a positive function. If $F$ and $\tilde F$ denote norms induced by the Riemannian inner products on $M$ and $\tilde M$ respectively, we get
$$F(v)=\sqrt{v^1v^1+w(r)\tilde{F}^2(\tilde{v})},$$
where $\tilde{v}$ is projection of v on $\tilde{M}$.
We generalize it to the form
$$F=\sqrt{w(v^1, r, \tilde{F})}. $$
Since F is positive homogeneous of degree one,  we have
$$F = \tilde F.  \sqrt{w(\frac{v^1}{\tilde{F}}, r, 1)}, $$
for $\tilde{F} \neq 0$. **Since $\{v\in T_x M \mid \tilde{F}=0\}$ is a one dimensional subspace of $T_x M$ ($x\in M$), the norm $F$ can be determined by its values on the open subset $\{v\in T_x M \mid \tilde{F} \neq 0\}$ by the continuity.** I don't know which theorem is used that this result came up? Can someone explain it for me?

Comment: The more I reread, the less I understand. Is the question about evaluating $g$ on "vectors tangent to $r$ directions" or about extending to points where $w(r) = 0$, perhaps in some manifold containing $I \times \tilde{M}$ as a dense open set?

Comment: For starters, the formula for $F(v)$ is plain wrong. Where are the $\tilde M$ components of $v$?

Comment: @Andrew I am just modified the question with the more details. My question is about evaluating the norm F on T_x M.

Comment: For my purpose,  i need the form of the norm F is as follows.    $$F = \tilde F.  \sqrt{w(\frac{v^1}{\tilde{F}}, r, 1)}, $$

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what is a quote from the text and what was written by you? I can't tell where it changes back to your own text. You can make long quotes by starting a paragraph with >.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, though I'm afraid I'm still not following: $g$ is an honest Riemannian metric on $I \times M$, so I'm not seeing the issue. Best guess is we're at an endpoint of $I$, and $w = 0$ at that endpoint, and we've partially or totally collapsed a copy of $M$ at that endpoint, but that still doesn't seem to jibe fully with the other details.